# install mcrypt on mac os maveriks

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt

I moved to mac os x and i set up the vhost for my laravel project but when i run it tell me Mcrypt PHP extension required. 
So i used this tuto http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/ and in stalled a new version of php 5.6.11 with mcrypt on it but when i try phpinfo() in a web page it still show me php 5.5.20 version and mcrypt is not running so how do i use my new in stalled version of php to run my project?

Comment: You may want to consider running in a virtual machine, for example using [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead). While it is possible to get OS X's PHP set up with mcrypt, install MySQL, and so on, it can be a lot easier just to use a pre-built (and Laravel-official) virtual box. Plus if you switch back to a different OS, you can take it with you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have two versions of php installed on your Mac. Use the command below to see the current version.

`$ php -v`

**Solution 1**

You can change the version by edit the configure file of apache.

`vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
find
`LoadModule php5_module` and change the 'so' to your new php56 you installed.

**Solution 2**

I recommend you use Homebrew to manage your packages on Mac.
(Homebrew: http://brew.sh/)

And this is how to install php56 after installed Homebrew:

install php: `$ brew install php56`

install mcrypt extension: `$ brew install php56-mcrypt`